# Admin only access to page, if statment doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm trying to give access to admin tools only to the admin.

**What I tried to do:** the session variable id, which is unique for every user.
first I checked if there is even a session, if there isn't I send the user to the index, than I check for the unique if of the admin "20" if the user's id is different than 20 I send him the the index.

**my problem:** my if statment doesn't work, I get sent back to index even when i'm logged-in as the admin.

**My code:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
    header('Location:index.php?b');
}
if($_SESSION['userId'] != 20){
      header('Location:index.php?a');
}

?>
```

`?a` and `?b` are for debugging, I get sent to `index.php?a` when I try to access the my page.

when I echo `$_SESSION['userId']` I get 20, so maybe something is wrong with the type?(although I checked and it says that `!=` shouldn't be effected by different types)

EDIT: sorry, I didn't describe what I wanted correctly, if the id of the user is 20 I want him to stay in the page, if it isn't I want to redirect him to index.

thanks!

Comment: Your first condition doesn't do a comparison, so it is automatically correct each time `$_SESSION['userId']` is set, even with a blank value.

Comment: You should use `exit();` after each header to make sure PHP does not continue to process.

Comment: what all say plus it should be "20" since it's a string not integer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard , isn't isset produce true or false? I set the $_SESSION['userId'] only when the user logs in

Comment: Yes, it judges truth and is done the way you have it set up. You should do two comparisons with an `&&` operator. `if(isset($_SESSION['userId']) && $_SESSION['userId'] != 20) { //send to index a} else {//send to index b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you perform one test when that test passes or fails the comparison is over. You should probably perform a comparison like this because you only want to redirect when the ID is not 20:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['userId']) && $_SESSION['userId'] != 20) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you! I used a version of this and it worked for me:         `if(isset($_SESSION['userId']) == false || $_SESSION['userId'] != 20)
    {
        header('Location:index.php');
        exit();
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Your first `if` condition checks if the session is set (which is true) so it redirects you to index. So you should do:

```php
session_start()
if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
    if($_SESSION['userId'] != 20){
        header('Location:index.php?a');
    }else{
        header('Location:index.php?b');
    }
}
```

Comment: session should be started first.

Answer (score 2):

Check if session is set and if so assign its value to a variable with the [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). Redirect using the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```php
<?php
session_start()
//$_SESSION['userId'] = 19; // Redirects to index.php?a
$_SESSION['userId'] = 20; // Redirects to index.php?b

// use the null coalesce operator and ternary
$id = $_SESSION['userId'] ?? null;
($id == '20') ? '' : Redirect('index.php?a');

echo 'Still in page ...';

// Ensure an exit() after redirect
function Redirect($url) {
  header('Location: ' . $url);
  exit();
}
//Output: Still in page ...
?>
```

## EDIT:

You can combine these steps to achieve this in one line:

```php
(($_SESSION['userId'] ?? null) == 20) ? '' : header('Location: index.php?a');
```

This returns `$_SESSION['userId']` if it's set and not null, otherwise it returns null. Then it checks this against the value `20` and uses it in the ternary operator to either do nothing (`''`) or redirect to `index.php`.

Comment: I didn't format what I wanted correctly, if the id of the user is 20 I want him to stay in the page, if it isn't I want to redirect him to index.

Comment: @Meon no problem, I've updated my answer to address this.